# calculation then and insert results into a csv in python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, dataset, sum

this is my first post but I am hoping you can tell me how to perform a calculation and insert the value within a csv data file.

For each row I want to be able to be able to take each 'uniqueclass' and sum the scores achieved in column 12. See example data below;

```
text1,Data,Class,Uniqueclass1,data1,data,2,data2,data3,data4,data5,175,12,data6,data7
text1,Data,Class,Uniqueclass1,data1,data,2,data2,data3,data4,data5,171,18,data6,data7
text1,Data,Class,Uniqueclass2,data1,data,4,data2,data3,data4,data5,164,5,data6,data7
text1,Data,Class,Uniqueclass2,data1,data,4,data2,data3,data4,data5,121,21.5,data6,data7
text2,Data,Class,Uniqueclass2,data1,data,4,data2,data3,data4,data5,100,29,data6,data7
text2,Data,Class,Uniqueclass2,data1,data,4,data2,data3,data4,data5,85,21.5,data6,data7
text3,Data,Class,Uniqueclass3,data1,data,3,data2,data3,data4,data5,987,35,data6,data7
text3,Data,Class,Uniqueclass3,data1,data,3,data2,data3,data4,data5,286,18,data6,data7
text3,Data,Class,Uniqueclass3,data1,data,3,data2,data3,data4,data5,003,5,data6,data7
```

So for instance the first Uniqueclass lasts for the first two rows. I would like to be able to therefore insert a subsquent value on that row which would be '346'(the sum of both 175 & 171.) The resultant would look like this:

```
text1,Data,Class,Uniqueclass1,data1,data,2,data2,data3,data4,data5,175,12,data6,data7,346
text1,Data,Class,Uniqueclass1,data1,data,2,data2,data3,data4,data5,171,18,data6,data7,346
```

I would like to be able to do this for each of the uniqueclass'

Thanks SMNALLY

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Open your python interpreter and try: ``"blah,230,bleh".split(',')``. It may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always like the `defaultdict` class for this type of thing.

Here would be my attempt:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class_col = 3
data_col = 11

# Read in the data
with open('path/to/your/file.csv', 'r') as f:
    # if you have a header on the file
    # header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
    data = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

# Sum the data for each unique class.
# assuming integers, replace int with float if needed
count = defaultdict(int)
for row in data:
    count[row[class_col]] += int(row[data_col])

# Append the relevant sum to the end of each row
for row in xrange(len(data)):
    data[row].append(str(count[data[row][class_col]]))

# Write the results to a new csv file
with open('path/to/your/new_file.csv', 'w') as nf:
    nf.write('\n'.join(','.join(row) for row in data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments! I will upvote your answer once I get to 15 points. :)

Comment: This code is brilliant, I tried playing around with it so that it would put the count at the end of the rather than the sum. However to no effect. If this is easy I would really appreciate a comment on how to do this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've been on holidays. To make it a count (of class instances) rather than a sum, replace `int(row[data_col])` with `1`.